# how to pass button_click to child window in C#?

Tags: c#

Can anyone here do me a favor?

I have a MainWindow with a HideButton and RetrieveButton. When I click on either one button, it will goes to another ChildWindow. My ChildWindow have a OKButton.

The question here, 
How to set if else statement in C# for pseudocode below?

```
private void OKButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // pseudocode
    if (HideButton in MainWindow is clicked)
    {
        // Perform the works
    }

    if(RetrieveButton in MainWindow is clicked)
    {
        // Perform other works
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

By, Aeris

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the child window on Retrieve or Hide you can easily pass parameters then either via the constructor or by setting a custom property:

```
ChildWindow child = new ChildWindow();
child.Retrieving = true;
child.Show();
```